# Which SE site do I use for text encoding?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd like to ask a question about how to type using a certain foreign numeral-set on a computer, but I can't figure out which Stack-Exchange site to use?

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like the kind of question that would fit on [**Super User**](https://superuser.com/). Make sure you check out their [help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) to see whether your question is something they'd consider on topic.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks so much.